# Lottie animation blurry on Chrome only

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, elementor, lottie, blurry

[image: Screenshot comparing how a logo looks on three different browsers]

A lottie animation I have produced looks very blurry in Chrome, but only on a non-retina screen. FF and Safari renders the logo well, but just Chrome renders it blurry.

I've searched and searched and added `image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;` and `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` and `transform: unset !important;` but none have solved the issue. I'm using elementor.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72404034/3001970

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome shows Lottie animation blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404034/chrome-shows-lottie-animation-blurry)